# Return value to a vector from a function

Tags: c++, vector

Im a totaly newbie! Im writing a program that uses separate files. In the main file Ive made a vector to store information from a struct which is placed in a separate header. I have constructed a function in a separate file to add objects from the structure. My problem is that I can't figure out how to return the objects from my function to my vector in the main file. And excuse me for my poor spelling!

This is my vector in the main file but before main():
`vector<Person> persons;`

And this is my function :

```
vector <Person> add(vector <Person> persons)
{
        cin.get();
        Person tmpPerson;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Add user information!" << endl;
        cout << "Firstname: ";
        getline(cin, tmpPerson.firstName);

        cout << "Lastname: ";
        getline(cin, tmpPerson.lastName);

        cout << "Weight in kg (x.x): ";
        cin >> tmpPerson.weigth;        
       //cin.get(); 

    persons.push_back(tmpPerson);
```

Comment: What is the exact problem with this code? E.g.: What happens, what errors do you get, ...

Comment: Your code is incomplete, you do not provide Person class definition and the end bracket of "do" is even missing. Please poste a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Pass persons by reference, not by value and return a reference (if you want the `add` function to be used in chain also return a reference instead of value). Anyway, it looks like you need to learn some C++ first.

Comment: Why not write a function that returns a `Person`, then use that to push persons into the vector?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do so. Simply pass the vector to the function by reference:

```
void add(vector<Person>& persons) {
  ....
  persons.push_back(tmpPerson);
}
```

The `persons` vector will be passed to the function [by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm), which means you will actually be working on the original copy.

Comment: Thanks! Gonna try that out! :)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much! :)